# ffmpeg : split a video using silencedetect?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to know if ffmpeg is able to split video in several parts using silencedetect? I saw silencedetect used on mp3s to remove silences, but never on a video like blackdetect is.

Comment: may be this thread will be of use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074224/how-to-split-video-or-audio-by-silent-parts

Answer (score 2):

You can use `silencedetect` with `filter_complex`. So you can select the required channels from the input video and get them through filters. Following is the FFmpeg command I'm suggesting.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -filter_complex "[0:a]silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=1[outa]" -map [outa] test1.mp3
```

This will give you the corresponding silent time periods and you can use them again to split the video. `[0:a]` refers to the first input file and `map` will get the filtered audio output to the output file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697596/using-ffmpeg-with-silencedetect-to-remove-audio-silence) you can find a good example for audio splitting. Same way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651654/ffmpeg-how-to-split-video-efficiently) video splitting is described.

Hope this helps you!